# Dlookup one Field determines another

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with two fields "Sending Category" and "Account". There is a table called PacingCategories with a column called "Category" (sending category pulls from this) and a column called "Account". I am trying to do a Dlookup. When the "sending category" is filled I need the "Account" field to autofill with the corresponding account. I have spent 2 hours researching and trying to get it to work but it won't update for some reason.

I have tried watching videos and reading online. I still am unsure what is going wrong.

```
Private Sub Sending_Category_AfterUpdate()

Me.Account = DLookup("Account", "PacingCategories", "[Sending Category]=" & "Category")

End Sub
```

I receive no error messages. It just doesn't autofill in the account number after the Sending Category. I know this should be easy. Thank you for looking. Matt

Comment: If [Sending Category] equates to a specific account then why would you need to save account? Save Category value into [Sending Category] field then use query joining tables to retrieve account. Use a multi-column combobox to pull Category and Account info. Textbox or VBA can reference combobox column by index. Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: The Category Values are saved into the Sending Category. Maybe that's the root of my issue with Dlookup? I like your idea though. One less field for my users to look at. Eventually the Category needs to be replaced by its corresponding Account #. The query would be perfect. Thanks for the Input

Comment: Gustav answer has correct structure for your DLookup. Yes, root of issue is trying to save data that should not be saved. Glad query approach resolves.

Answer (score 0):

*Category* and *[Sending Category]* are in each other's position. Also, don't put variable within quote marks. Including `.Value` doesn't hurt but is not needed because it is default for data controls.

Try with:

```
Me!Account = DLookup("Account", "PacingCategories", "Category=" & Me![Sending Category])
```

If *Category* is text, use apostrophe delimiters:

```
Me!Account = DLookup("Account", "PacingCategories", "Category='" & Me![Sending Category] & "'")
```

Comment: Both attempts comes back with the error "Microsoft Access cant find the field 'Category' referred to in your expression" Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When it is simply a Lookup, insted of using vba I usually put the Dlookup in ControlSource of control. I have a really simple database I created to control my books and used it for a example here:

The "Select Author" is a comboBox that selects the Author ID (There is a "Authors" table with Author ID (primary key), Given Name and Last Name).
The textBoxes "Author Given Name" and "Author Last Name" are filled in automatically on the update of the "Select Author" ComboBox.

[image]

On the ControlSource of both LastName and GivenName textboxes, put the Dlookup function:

[image]

After that, I just use either Macro or VBA to update the whole form on the update of the "Select Author" Combo Box (in my case, I used macro because it is really fast and simple):
[image]

[image]

I like to reserve VBA for heavy lifting data manipulation, MS access provides shortcuts for the simple stuff, and I don't mind using them.

Comment: Yes, use VBA to save calculated values although saving simple calculated values should not be necessary. Saving author names to another table is duplication of data, should just save the ID.

Comment: Exactly. In this case, in the "Books" table I only save the Author ID. If I need the name I just perfom a simple query/DlookUp.

Comment: So why would you even need macro to update form? Domain aggregate can perform slowly. Simpler approach is to have Author combobox multi-column then expression in textbox can reference combobox column by index to grab name parts.

Comment: The textboxes for GIven and last name have a Dlookup attacjed to the value of the comboBox with the author ID. If I don't update it as soon as I chose the author ID, they will be empty.

I rather, for aesthetic reasons, have two text box then just the combo box. Performance was not an issue in this case, it is just for my personal book collection.